# How to check for multiple values in (.Where) statement in order to select same types but with varying values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
        var results = _db.CatSchemas.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TypeName == "Programs")
            .Categories.Where(c => c.FilterValToCatMaps.Where
                (fm => fm.FilterValue.Value == age && fm.FilterValue.Value == ProgType).Count() > 0)
                    .Select(c => c.Category1);
```

If I remove `&& fm.FilterValue.Value == ProgType` the query works but then of course only returns
the results filtered by `age` only.

I require to select only the `Categories` which have `FilterValToCatMaps` that have `FilterValue.Value` equal to that specified in the parameter `age` and `ProgType`. `FilterValues` can only contain one Value and all related `FilterValToCatMaps` and respective `FilterValues`  should be present in the required category.

The `(fm => fm.FilterValue.Value == age && fm.FilterValue.Value == ProgType)` statement I presume tries to check if the two parameter values are true for the **same** `FilterValToCatMap.FilterValue` and not check if other `FilterValToCatMap.FilterValue` related to the category contain the **next** parameter value.

FilterValToCatMaps - Table

LineID | FilterValueID | **CatID**

FilterValues - Table

LineID | **Value** | DisplayName | FilterID

Comment: What's the problem? I can't understand your problem, show me example, where i'll can see, what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of categories as the result, you should generally start with `_db.Categories`.

Also, because you require both `FilterValues`, not either or, you can split the clause into 2 `Where` clauses.

```
var results = _db.Categories
  .Where( c => c.CatSchema.TypeName == "Programs" )
  .Where( c => c.FilterValToCatMaps.Any( fm => fm.FilterValue.Value == age ) )
  .Where( c => c.FilterValToCatMaps.Any( fm => fm.FilterValue.Value == ProgType ) )
```

Comment: I think, that there is no difference between In a row .Where.Where or in one statement with &&

Comment: @Likurg Absolutely - I just think it looks better. In any case, there needs to be two separate `Any` clauses.

Comment: Looks the goods. Though would that retrieve only categories that each have both the required `FilterValToCatMap.FilterValue.Value` as I need or will this retrieve all categories where the  `FilterValToCatMap.FilterValue.Value` equals to either one of the parameters (Age or ProgType).

Comment: @NicholasButler Agree with you

Comment: All `Where` clauses must be true, so it's what you want: an `And` not an `Or`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
 var results = _db.CatSchemas.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TypeName == "Programs")
        .Categories.Where(c => c.FilterValToCatMaps.Any
            (fm => fm.FilterValue.Value == age && fm.FilterValue.Value == ProgType));
```

So it will return the categories that have FilterValToCapMaps with any that query.

BTW, `fm.FilterValue.Value == age && fm.FilterValue.Value == ProgType` is only true where age and ProgType are equals.